# multipart/form-data request with no files on Python Requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'll use multipart/form-data with no files through Requests.

```
        resp = requests.post(~~~, files={
        'a':f,
        'b':g,
        'c':e,
        'd':q,
        'e':w,
        'd':r
    })
```

It says `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`

I think if `files` dictionary contains more than 2 elements, it raises an error.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you trying to assign a method that returns 1 object to 4 objects?

Comment: @Nae yup, but I don't think this is that kind of error. Even after removing assignation, the error stays still.

Comment: Can you provide some context? I didn't get this error for more than two files.

Comment: Nevermind. I changed my mind to not submitting more than 2 files with multipart/fomr-data

Answer (score 0):

As per the [requests documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), the value from your dictionary should be a tuple.

```
resp = requests.post(~~~, files={
    'a': ('',f),
    ...
})
```